# Find specific char inside delimiter

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have this string:

`(40.959953710949506, -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299, -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065, -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255, -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785, -74.21067086616523)`

I need to grab the commas inside the parentesis for further processing, and I want the commas spliting the groups to remain.

Let's say I want to replace the target commas by  `FOO`, the result should be:

```
(40.959953710949506 FOO -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299 FOO -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065 FOO -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255 FOO -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785 FOO -74.21067086616523)
```

I want a Regular Expression that is not language specific.

Comment: why do you want regex? is that some homework?

Comment: Something like, I need to do something and I don't use language functions/loops for it. Regex is more suited for accomplish it, and I want to learn how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```py
import re

s = "(40.959953710949506, -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299, -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065, -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255, -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785, -74.21067086616523)"
s = re.sub(r",(?=[^()]+\))", " FOO", s)
print(s)

# (40.959953710949506 FOO -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299 FOO -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065 FOO -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255 FOO -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785 FOO -74.21067086616523)
```

We use a positive lookahead to only replace commas where `)` comes before `(` ahead in the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find all `,` that are not preceded by a `)` like this:

```
(?<!\)),
```

---

> I don't want some language specific functions for this

The format of the above regex is not language specific as can be seen in the following Code Snippet or [this regex101 snippet](https://regex101.com/r/yBV05C/1):

```js
const x = '(40.959953710949506, -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299, -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065, -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255, -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785, -74.21067086616523)';

const rgx = /(?<!\)),/g;

console.log(x.replace(rgx, ' XXX'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
inp = "(40.959953710949506, -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299, -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065, -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255, -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785, -74.21067086616523)"
output = re.sub(r'\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)', lambda m: r'(' + m.group(1) + r' FOO ' + m.group(2) + r')', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> (40.959953710949506 FOO -74.18210638344726),(40.95891663745299 FOO -74.10606039345703),(40.917472246121065 FOO -74.09582940498359),(40.921752754230255 FOO -74.16397897163398),(40.95248644043785 FOO -74.21067086616523)

The strategy here is to capture the two numbers in each tuple in separate groups.  Then, we replace by connecting the two numbers with `FOO` instead of the original comma.